# Set up SearchDisplayController to search UITableView items

Tags: iphone, search, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UITableView in my app, and would like to use a SearchBar with SearchDisplayController to search the table items. I've added a SearchBar, connected the SearchBar with an IBOutlet, but have no idea as to how to make it actually do anything... Anyone got a link to a good tutorial or something? Let me know if you need any of my code.

UPDATE: I found a property called searchResultsDataSource here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchDisplayController/searchResultsDataSource

But how do I use it?